# To make a if-clause in Sh

Tags: if-statement, sh

I have the following in a file which is sourced both by .bashrc and .zshrc. The syntax is from the [site](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~cs300/Sh/lecture.pt2.html).

```
if $SHELL=/bin/zsh                                                               
         then
     # to not java .class when running java 
             myclasslist () { reply=(${$(ls *.class)%.class}) }
             compctl -K myclasslist java
fi
```

Both Zsh and Bash go upset of it.

**How can you make a if -clause in sh?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your condition in the test operator (as well as quotes to get in the habit):

In shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/zsh" ]; then
       # do your thing
fi
```

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$SHELL" == "/bin/zsh" ]; then
    # just do it!
fi
```

Comment: Your answer suggests me that there is no way to source the same file for Bash/Zsh, since we cannot use the same syntax in the if -clause. Is this right?

Comment: @Masi - I haven't explored the shell nuances too much but I think as long as you have the shebang line set (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`), sourcing the file "shouldn't" be a problem.  It works for me when I source the first example from within bash w/o a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `test` alias `[` command:

```
if [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/zsh" ]
then
    myclasslist () { reply=(${$(ls *.class)%.class}) }
    compctl -K myclasslist java
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

On the web site you mention, they do not use the test operator ([]) because they say:

> For example, cat returns 0 if it runs
>   successfully, and 1 if it encounters
>   an error

The if must be followed by a "boolean statement" and if this statement returns 0, the "then" is actually executed...

In your case, Seth's answer is what you're looking for.